# How to remove certain coordinates from a list

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and was trying to make a grid function which returns all the coordinates in the grid as a list. I want to filter this list to remove any coordinates where `x = y` given `[(x,y)]` (essentially getting rid of all the diagonal coordinates in the grid) but I'm not sure how to do it. Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

```
grid :: Int -> [(Int,Int)]
grid n = [(x,y) | x <- [0..n], y <- [0..n]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use filter.

The following predicate is `True` for non-diagonal elements:

```
 predicate (x,y)=x/=y
```

Then you can define your filter:

```
gridFilter g=filter predicate g
```

Run it with:

```
gridFilter $ grid 2
```

Yields:

```
[(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1)]
```

Of course you can also make it a one-liner:

```
gridFiltered=filter (\(x,y)->x/=y) $ grid 2
```

Comment: @Daniel's answer is way simpler if he already has a list comprehension imho

Answer (score 2):

Your function was good enough, just add a filter on it:

```
grid :: Int -> [(Int,Int)]
grid n = [(x,y) | x <- [0..n], y <- [0..n], x /= y]
```

using a filter (`x /= y`) in the list comprehensions is pretty simple and describes what you try to accomplish.

Comment: Haskell uses `/=` instead of `!=` like most languages use. (I have no idea why Haskell did not copy C here while doing so for e.g. `&&`,`||` and `==`)

Comment: @chi, exactly, i just missed that, thanks for fixing it.